# Evince: Hotkey for highlighting

Tags: evince

I couldn't find a hotkey for activating the highlight feature.

Did I miss something or is there no such key combination?

Comment: Much needed ... even I am looking but could not find anything on GNOME evince page :( very unfortunate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> allows to highlight text. However, it is enabled [since Evince 3.30](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/blob/gnome-3-30/NEWS#L97). That is, it does not work on Ubuntu 18.04, which ships Evince 3.28.4.

Up to 3.32, it is missing in the documentation. See [issue 1200](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/issues/1200).

Answer (score 0):

**To get the keybindings in Ubuntu 18.04**, you can install the latest version of evince from snap, as suggested by [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1118796/how-do-i-install-evince-3-28-or-newer-on-ubuntu-xenial-16-04-lts) (currently it is 40.4 as opposed to apt's 3.28.4).